# How to make ngx-bootstrap modal resize horizontally?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have a working ngx-bootstrap modal created in angular 5.
I wanted to allow user to resize the width of the modal after it is displayed.
does any css properties must be included.?

```js
config = {
    backdrop: true,
    ignoreBackdropClick: true
  };
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.config);
    
  }
```

```html
<ng-template #template style="width:35%;margin-left:105px;margin-top:-4px;background-color: #ffffdd">
    <div style="padding-right:-18px">
        <button type="button" style="width:25px" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
            <span style="font-size:2.5rem;margin-left:-1%" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align: left;padding-left: 5px;background-color: #ffffdd">
       <pre> {{data}}</pre>
    </div>
</ng-template>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Create template modal</button>
```

[Wanted to allow user to drag and increase the width of ngx modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXL9x.gif)

Answer (score 1):

The size of the Bootstrap Modal depends on two classes: `'modal-lg'` is for Large Modal and `'modal-sm'` is for small modal.

You can use `[ngClass]` to toggle these classes like this:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" [ngClass]="bigSize ? 'modal-lg' : 'modal-sm'">
```

And toggle the `bigSize` boolean property on a user event, click of a button for eg:

```
<button (click)="bigSize = !bigSize">Toggle Size</button>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toggle-bootstrap-modal-size?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks Sidd    But u are calling modal from the click event of html button. I wanted call form the script with a template. once the template is wrapped in the show function . It become inaccessible to adjust style attributes.

Comment: Is it possible to do same thing using template.  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.config);
    
  }

Comment: @Vinayk94, can you please clone my StackBlitz to implement your use case and share it with me so that I could have a look into it.

Comment: Please see the image below to understand what I'm trying to achieve. I have referred to many documentations for doing this But no success . Wanted to allow users to increase the width of ngx-modal instead of swapping classes like model-lg and modal-sm on click.                                                           
    --                  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXL9x.gif

Answer (score 0):

In CSS file need to add below lines

```
::ng-deep .modal-content{
  width: 800px;
}
```